# How do I close this dialog using JQuery? Using Coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

I'm putting together a new app and, while I normally use JQuery for things like this I'd like to compare it to Coffeescript and choose the right approach. Moreover, I want to make sure I understand how to invoke JQuery correctly using coffeescript.

The Dialog is in the following div:

```
<div class="alert-message error">
  <a class="close" href="#">X</a>
  <p>Here is some error text</p>
</div>
```

The styling puts an 'X' on the right margin of the dialog. When the user clicks the 'X', the entire div needs to disappear.

What JQuery code or Coffescript code would I use to close the dialog? This dialog could appear on any page in the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.close').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().hide(); //finds parent element of clicked .close and hides it
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Definitely works. I was hoping for the equivalent coffesscript as well -- anyone?

Comment: @Kevin All you have to do to CoffeeScript-ize it is replace `function` with `->` and ditch the `{` curly braces `}`. The #1 rule of CoffeeScript is "It's Just JavaScript." :)

Comment: @Trevor Thanks. I actually did just that and worked it out. This was a simple example, I was really mainly hoping I'd see different examples of coffeescript approaches. [btw - can you pls contact me through my twitter?]

Answer (score 2):

Here is samura code using coffeescript

```
$('.close').click() ->
    $(this).parent().hide()

// or on 1 line
$('.close').click() -> $(this).parent().hide()

// fat arrow version, not 100% sure on this, typing from ipad
$('.close').click(e) => $(e.target).parent().hide()
```

http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/

Comment: I was able to make this work only after adding a leading 'jQuery -> ' to the beginning of your line one. So one line would be: jQuery ->  $(".close").click -> $(this).parent().hide()

Comment: @Kevin That's going to be equally true of the JS version, then. Using `jQuery ->` (or, equivalently, `$ ->`... unless you're doing something unusual, you'll find that `$ == jQuery`) just ensures that the your code runs after the DOM has been loaded, so that the `.close` elements from your page's HTML exist when you make the `$('.close')` selection.